# JSON post request don't work

Tags: objective-c, iphone, json, xcode, post

I am using this code and is not working. NSLog in post and get method is empty.
I need post raw data. I write parameters in Body - raw and it is work (Chrome- POSTMAN).

this parameters:

```
[
    {
    "user":    "admin",
    "pass":    "admin123",
    "delete_book": 0,
    "add_book": false,
    "read_book": false,
    "bookprice": 0,
    "person": "",
    "book": 0  
    }
]
```

my code for post method:

```
 NSString * paramters = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"[{\"user\": \"admin\",\"pass\": \"admin123\",\"delete_book\": \"0\",\"add_book\": \"false\",\"read_book\": \"false\",\"bookprice\": \"0\",\"person\": \"\",\"book\": \"0\"}]"];
    NSError *error;

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

  //  NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:paramters options:0 error:&error];
  NSData *postData = [paramters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if([data length] > 0)
                {
                    NSError *err = nil;
                    NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&err];
                    NSLog(@"Result : %@",dictResponse);
                }
                else{
                    NSLog(@"Failed To Get Response.");
                }
            });

    }];

    [postDataTask resume];
```

**I SOLVE THE PROBLEM**
This is solution: 
NSData *postData = [paramters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: is the post request in correct format?

Comment: I don't know, i know i need JSON post request.

Comment: i mean is the url in right format?

Comment: as i can see, you are trying to post the parameters in the url.com which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have real URL in my code, this is example.

Comment: There's no JSON. What Content-Type do you need to send?

Comment: @WildWorld your service is not post, its get becuase your are creating querystring there. pls double check it.

Comment: When I try in POSTMAN It works with method POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I think you missed & at the beginning of the post string,just before the user parameter

```
NSString  *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&user=admin&pass=admin123&delete_book=0&add_book=false&read_book=false&bookprice=0&person=0&book=0"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://your-url"]]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

     //check here if nsdata is nil or not
      NSLog(@"nsdata is %@",data);
    //if it is nil , then there should be something wrong with the url

    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);

    //convert into JSON
     NSError *e = nil;
        NSData *jsonData = [requestReply dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

        NSLog(@"json is %@",JSON); //check json here
}] resume];
```

Edit: POSTMAN reference:

[image]

Comment: requestReply is still empty.

Comment: try to nslog NSdata and check if it is nill or not

Comment: use NSUTF8StringEncoding encoding

Comment: When I NSLog postData I received <2655706f 7261626e 69736b6f 496d653d 61646d69 6e264765 736c6f3d 61646d69 6e313233 264f6473 7472616e 694b6e6a 69676f3d 3026446f 64616a4d 65645072 65627261 6e653d66 616c7365 265a656c 696d5072 65627261 74693d66 616c7365 264f6365 6e614b6e 6a696765 3d30264f 63656e6a 6576616c 65633d30 264b6e6a 6967613d 30>

Comment: convert the reply string into json and try to NSLog the json repsonse

Comment: did u try my answer? is JSON nill ?

Comment: yes JSON is nill nsdata and requestReply is not nill

Comment: then try to test the url with POSTMAN chrome app and see if you are really getting the data or not

Comment: In POSTMAN I need choose POST, copy link and add parameters? When I click button Send it is empty

Comment: can u hide the url and take the screenshot?

Comment: you have to enter the values in form-data instead of URL params

Comment: I add parameters in URL Parameter Key, when I write parameters in Body - > x-www-form-urlencoded I get the entire code of website

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84010/discussion-between-t-77-and-wildworld).

Comment: I edit my question. I need post raw data. I write parameters in Body - raw and it is work (POSTMAN).

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code...
Hope it works for you

```
-(void)postServerCall{
        NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=admin&pass=admin123&delete_book=0&add_book=false&read_book=false&bookprice=0&person=0&book=0"];

        NSOperationQueue *backgroundQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://PostUrl.com"]]];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:backgroundQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"result....%@",result);
            }
        }];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (void)callPOSTAPIWithParams:(NSDictionary *)params andCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *result))completionHandler
{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",<Your HOST API URL>]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&err];
    //    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:requestData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    //    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                  {
                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                          if([data length] > 0)
                                          {
                                              NSError *err = nil;
                                              NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];
                                              NSLog(@"Result : %@",dictResponse);
                                          }
                                          else{
                                              NSLog(@"Failed To Get Response.");
                                          }
                                      });
                                  }];

    [task resume];
}
```

**`How to use`**

```
NSDictionary *paramters = @{@"param1":@"value1"};
[Global callPOSTAPIUsingSessionWithParams:paramters andCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *result) {
NSLog(@"check result");
}];
```

Comment: Display -> Result : (null). I have parameters like NSDictionary *paramters = @{@"user":@"admin",@"pass":@"admin123"...};

Comment: check with your apis whether its post and json supported, verify with "POSTMAN" tool